# Android Kotlin: Creating RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I am a newbie to Android Development and I am stuck with creating a RecyclerView in fragment.

I created 2 adapters (AdapterAll.kt for multiple fragments under Tablayout and MainAdapter.kt for a fragment that I want to create recyclerview on) but cannot invoke MainAdapter.kt.
MainActivity.kt invokes AdapterAll.kt but not MainAdapter.kt.
I believe this is why I can create Tablayout with fragments but cannot create a Recyclerview on a fragment.

Thank you very much!

Codes are below:

MainActivity.kt

```
import controller.AdapterAll
import controller.MainAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewPager.adapter = AdapterAll(supportFragmentManager)
        tabLayoutId.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        tabLayoutId.setTabTextColors(Color.GRAY, Color.parseColor("white"))

        recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter()
    }
}
```

AdapterAll.kt

```
class AdapterAll(fragmentManager: FragmentManager): 
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return Function1()
            1 -> return Function2()
            2 -> return Function3()
            3 -> return Function4()
            4 -> return Function5()
            5 -> return Function6()
            6 -> return Function7()
        }
        return Function1()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 7
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return "Function 1"
            1 -> return "Function 2"
            2 -> return "Function 3"
            3 -> return "Function 4"
            4 -> return "Function 5"
            5 -> return "Function 6"
            6 -> return "Function 7"
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

MainAdapter.kt

```
class MainAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 10
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_function1, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.textView_video_title.text = "123"
    }

}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

}
```

Comment: So everything builds fine but you are not able to see your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I believe all are build fine. That's right I am not able to see RecyclerView. Additionally, I don't get any error message so I am thinking this is to do with not invoking MainAdapter.kt.

Comment: Add this layout `R.layout.fragment_function1`

Comment: So your suggestion is to create a xml file under layout? I already have fragment_function1 but still cannot invoke MainAdapter.kt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Adapter is ok. If I am not wrong you want a recyclerView in your Fragments, but why you create a recyclerView in you Activity. Create a recyclerView in your Fragments and set the MainAdapter.kt in the recyclerView.

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

    view.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    view.recyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter()


    return view
}}
```

Comment: Aha did some adjustments and issue resolved now. Thank you!